# How to integrated google-play-services in android studio

Tags: android, google-play-services

I got my app integrated with Firebase admob , it works fine with those apps that are already installed google-play-services.

but I wanna put the  google-play-services in app for those apps that are **NOT** installed or pack it up for automatically for installing. It's **NOT** an option for popping up a dialog and downloading it, because  google had already banned in our country.

here are my gradle file settings

```
   dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

    }

----------------------------------
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Even if you add them in app, they won't work.

Comment: Can't be, I've seen an app , it works fine without google-play-services installed, i just wanna show admob, nothing else.